# Can I use the Facebook graph api to get user's friends profiles pictures?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, facebook

I'm new to facebook development, after testing the adobe api in a flash game  I decided to test using the graph api communicating with my flash game. After doing basic stuff like connecting and getting my user's data, i was wondering if it's posible to get my user's friends profile pcitures, so i can pass them to UILoaders inside my flash game and show them.

If anyone can point me to examples of basic actions which use the facebook graph api, like invite friends or posting to the wall for example, that would be wonderful.

thanks.

update:

Using Nathan's suggestion I tried to get my friends and it worked:

```
$friends= $facebook->api('/me/friends?token='.$session['access_token']);
var_dump($friends);
```

Then I tried to get my friend's pictures with:

```
foreach ($friends['data'] as $friend)
    {
        $picture= $facebook->api('/'.$friend['id'].'/photo');
    }
```

But it didn't work. any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: is this still possible with the updated graph api?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You first have to get the list of friends https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=... then for each of the friends you can request http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture That will give you the url of their current profile photo.

Comment: I had success getting my friends, but nothing with my friend's pictures. I updated the question to see if you could find the problem.

Comment: The problem is that getting the photo isnt an api call. The graph url actually will just redirect you to the url. I dont know much about flash, but if I wanted to use the photo of a user for example, I would do this: <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/photo" /> So rather than making the $facebook->$api call just bind your photo to the url.

Comment: Did you get this solved? If so, please consider marking my answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Maybe it's a difference between php and javascript (I'm still quite a noob with the facebook api) but to me it's not 'photo', but 'picture': http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture/ which will redirect to some other url (e.g. http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif)

Comment: That is exactly the same as what I wrote only he filtered the fields which reduces the amount of data sent back. However, the filter is not needed and was not part of the question. Also, he left out the most important part which is retrieving the actual image.

Comment: Actually, this method only returns the name and id of all FB friends. @darki699's method allows you to request more information, provided your access_token allows it.

Answer (score 64):

Easiest way yet was not posted here:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[oauth_token]&fields=name,id,picture
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why it took so long to find it. Thank you.

Comment: +1 but i am getting small size of images. For this i need to again hit another service "https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture?width=100&height=100" can you merge both the query in once ?

Comment: This worked like a charm. just one question. It gives me a picture object like this: "picture": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/....", 
          "is_silhouette": false
        }
      }

Is there a way to get url element directly ??

Comment: @Mangesh

Get bigger pictures by doing a nested call, defining width(or height):

    `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[oauth_token]&fields=name,id,picture.width(400)`

or by type:

    `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[oauth_token]&fields=name,id,picture.type(large)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get the photos this way : `/'.$friend['id'].'/photo`

Instead you have to loop through the albums first using : `/'.$friend['id'].'/albums`

Then for each album id you should use : `/'.$album['id'].'/photos`

This way you will reach the ID's of the pictures in that album. Then with the picture Id you had, you can get the photo `/'.$picture['id'].'/picture`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same functionality and just noticed that it is not possible anymore (at the time of writing: 2019-11-17, api v5.0).

If you try to call `/me/friends?fields=friends{name,id,profile_pic}` you would receive an empty array of friends:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 823
  }
}
```

Graph explorer shows this debug message: `Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app.`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($friends['data'] as $friend)
    {
        $picture= $facebook->api('/'.$friend['id'].'/photo?token='.$session['access_token']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html and it's too simple.

example :

```
    System.out.println("picture of publisher : "+facebook.getPictureURL(feed.get(41).getFrom().getId()));
```