# How to access friends album in Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I am developing a Facebook application, where my application will aggregate all the photos of my friends in their albums. How will i achieve using graph api and C#?

Answer (score 1):

First, look at this answer: [**Can I use the Facebook graph api to get user's friends** profiles pictures ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882573/can-i-use-the-facebook-graph-api-to-get-users-friends-profiles-pictures)
This will let you know how to generally use the graph api to get the to the friends. If you use `albums` instead of `photo`, you should get all the albums of a friend.

To get there, you will also need the [**friends_photos** permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). I don't know if it is still up to date, but maybe you will need [some more permissions](http://ericwconner.com/?p=137).

I'm no C# developer, but these links will help you:

- [C# Facebook Graph API Library](http://hernan.amiune.com/labs/facebook/c-sharp-facebook-graph-api-library.html)
- [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)
- [Facebook API from C# – Getting the list of friends](http://dennisdel.com/?p=185)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook recently made a nice tool you can use to explore how to get the details you need. It's called the Graph API Explorer and can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

But what is said in the other answer is correct. First you get the list of friends. Then their albums, and then the photos in the albums. Once you get the hang of the Graph API it's quite easy, but it requires a bit of tinkering to figure out at first.

If you are using C# you can use a WebRequest to get the data. Whenever you access http://graph.facebook.com/whateveryouwant it will return a string of JSON-data. This you can parse using a JSON-librabry like litJSON.

I have made an application that gets the profile photos, and it is not that hard. Just remember to get the right permissions.

The easiest way to do this is to use the Javascript API to get the loginstatus and then get some permissions. If you set cookies: true when you init the Facebook API you can get the accesss_token from the cookie. The cookie is named "fbs_YOURAPPID".

Also you need to make a developer app to get an access_token.